# Python and Bash command line env vars were handled different?

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

$ cat test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
import os
print (os.environ.get('test'))
```

$ test=4 python test.py

```
4
```

$ test=4; python test.py

```
None
```

While in shell I got different with python:

$ test=4; echo $test

```
4
```

But :

$ test=2
$ test=4 echo $test

```
2
```

So I am confused about how python and bash handle the situation. Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the difference between shell and environment variable.

Here,

```
test=4 python test.py
```

passes `test=4` to `python`'s environment, so you will get the variable `test` inside the script.

Whereas

```
test=4; python test.py
```

creates a shell variable that is available only in the current shell session (that is why you are getting the value from shell just fine)  i.e. will not be propagated to the environment.

To make a variable environment variable so that all subprocesses inherit the variable i.e. make the variable available in processes' environment, the usual way on any POSIX shell is to `export` the variable:

```
export test=4; python test.py
```

---

In your last case:

```
$ test=2
$ test=4 echo $test
2
```

the expansion of variable `test` happening before the `echo` built-in is run.

You need to use some method to preserve the expansion for later:

```
$ test=2
$ test=4 sh -c 'echo $test'
4
```

Comment: how about last case?

Comment: I can understand "happening before the echo built-in is run." . why it don't like python pass the var into the command's env.  `sh -c` seem open a new shell like python. So the parsing step. look env it aready was.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the variable for Python.

```
$ export test=4
```

Then execute your Python script:

```
$ ./test.py
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you get `2` with `test=2; test=4; echo $test`, as it definitely should be `4`.

Comment: I change the question. miss write.

Answer (score 1):

This ...

```
test=4 python test.py
```

... is a single `python` command, with variable `test` explicitly set in its environment, whereas this ...

```
test=4; python test.py
```

... is two separate commands.  The first tells bash to set variable `test` (without marking it for export) in the current shell, and the second is the `python` command.  Naturally, Python will not see the variable in its environment.  But if you afterward do

```
echo $test
```

then the *the shell* (not the `echo command`) expands the variable reference to its value as it processes the command line.  The resulting expanded command is

```
echo 4
```

, which does what you would expect.